# PHP Xdebug installation settings

Tags: php, xdebug

Here are my [php xdebug settings](http://screencast.com/t/Z4Ls7ULYoAZl)

When I run my php code I get the errors in [this format](http://screencast.com/t/rtkk2CDrd)

However xdebug is perfectly working with netbeans but xdebug not showing errors in formatted manner.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

check your php.ini if you have the

```
html_errors = On
```

and confirm it from your phpinfo()

Comment: yes "html_errors" is on in php.ini [php.ini screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/rGN0FzuUu)